# ggplot2 per year

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, line-plot

I have a dataframe which contains productivity measure by date.
the date starts from 05/04/2013 to 07/11/2014.
The productivity measure is for 6 organisational unit

Data looks like this:

```
> str(prods)
'data.frame':   588 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ SOM  : Factor w/ 7 levels "BVG1 Scotland",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Skill: Factor w/ 1 level "A": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Date : Date, format: "2013-04-05" "2013-04-12" "2013-04-19" "2013-04-26" ...
 $ Prod : num  2.97 2.94 2.87 2.95 2.97 2.97 2.97 2.94 2.86 2.98 ...
 $ Month: num  4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 ...
 $ Year : num  2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 ...
```

Summary:

```
> summary(prods)
                           SOM     Skill        Date                 Prod           Month            Year     
 BVG1 Scotland               :84   A:588   Min.   :2013-04-05   Min.   :2.370   Min.   : 1.00   Min.   :2013  
 BVG11 Highlands & IslandsA  :84           1st Qu.:2013-08-28   1st Qu.:2.888   1st Qu.: 4.75   1st Qu.:2013  
 BVG12 North East ScotlandA  :84           Median :2014-01-20   Median :3.030   Median : 7.00   Median :2014  
 BVG13 Central ScotlandA     :84           Mean   :2014-01-20   Mean   :3.029   Mean   : 6.75   Mean   :2014  
 BVG14 South East ScotlandA  :84           3rd Qu.:2014-06-14   3rd Qu.:3.180   3rd Qu.: 9.00   3rd Qu.:2014  
 BVG15 West Central ScotlandA:84           Max.   :2014-11-07   Max.   :3.510   Max.   :12.00   Max.   :2014  
 BVG16 South West ScotlandA  :84
```

I simply want draw a line plot using ggplot2 showing 2013 and 2014 `"Prod"` 
I can draw Actual prod to date as show below:
[image]

The code I used is:

```
ggplot(prods, aes(x = Date, y = Prod, group = SOM)) + 
     geom_line(lwd = 1.3, colour = "red") +
     ylab("Actual Productivity") + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
     facet_wrap(~ SOM)
```

It would be nice to show prod by year i.e. 2013 line with purple color and 2014 line with red for example.

any help would be highly appreciated.

### regards,

This is what I did:

```
ggplot(prods[Year==2013,], aes(x = Date, y = Prod, group = SOM)) + 
 geom_line(lwd = 1.3, colour = "purple") +
 ylab("Actual Productivity") + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
 geom_line(data=prods[Year==2014,], aes(x = Date, y = Prod, group = SOM),lwd = 1.3, colour = "red") +
        scale_color_manual("Period", values = c("purple","red"), labels = c("2013","2014")) +
 facet_wrap(~ SOM)
```

I am not getting any error but there is no legend popping up on the image. It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: not really clear what you want. the same plot but with different colour lines or split up the panels by year so you have `2*7` panels? Also can you provide enough data to make small reproducible example?

Comment: I want the same plot with 1 line representing 2013 and the other line 2014. The current plots shown above is a continues plot from 2013 to 2014

Answer (score 0):

```
 prods <- data.frame(Prod=c(1:10,1:10),
                     Date=rnorm(20),
                     year=rep(c(2013,2014,2013,2014),each=5),
                     SOM=rep(letters[1:2],each=10))
```

above makes fake data then code below subsets on year. you don't have to make a year column like i did you could subset on your actual data column itself.    The below plots once for 2013 and once for 2014.

```
ggplot(prods[prods$year==2013,], aes(x = Date, y = Prod, group = SOM)) + 
 geom_line(lwd = 1.3, colour = "purple") +
 geom_line(data=prods[prods$year==2014,], 
           aes(x = Date, y = Prod, group = SOM),lwd = 1.3, colour = "red") +
 ylab("Actual Productivity") + 
 theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
 facet_wrap(~ SOM)
```

[image]

Comment: This was great. I am getting an error using legend as I need to display the legend stating purple line is for 2013 and red for 2014

Comment: .... ok but you need to tell me the error or show the code your using or ask a new question. but you may have to plot invisible points/lines to get a legend, make a legend separate and add it, or use geom-point instead of line for colours in general, perhaps connecting them with a black line.

Comment: Just added the answer but cant see the legend and there is no error

Comment: you I'm not surprised there is no legend. I would ask a new question for this, i think the answer i gave met the needs of your original question.